# Binding "this" in JS object

Tags: javascript, oop, static, this

I'm trying to "reverse-engineer" JS code of one of my favorite web game. I'm not beginner in web developing, but JS is not my strength (nor english, sorry), I'm more backend programmer.

The code is full of such "objects":

```
var Foo = {
  prop: {...},
  prop2: [...],
  bar: function(val) {
    this.prop.k = val;
    Foo.doSomething();
  },
  doSomething: function() {
    var my = Foo.prop;
    ...
    return this.prop2;
  },
};

...somehere on the page...
<input type="text" name="in" value="Pretty text" onclick="Foo.bar(this.value)" />
```

As far as I understand it, it's object Foo made from anonymous class, making it somewhat static. But I'm very confused by using **this** and **Foo** as object name. It seems to me randomly used, one or another. It's not related to properties or functions, both are used both ways. Even in the same method is used both. I think, that in this case are **this** and **Foo** the same. When I try to make such an objects and dump them in console, this and Foo returns the same.

Can anyone explain to me, where can be a difference, please? Or can it be just something lost in translation, because original code is minified?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = {
  something: 'something',
  log: function() {
    return this.something
  },
  log2: function() {
    return x.something
  }
}
```

If you run the above code, you can see that the log() method and log2() method both return the same result. Which concludes that `this` and `x` refers to the same object in this scenario. Yours might be the same case if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Can't really tell. Idk who would ever use the object name instead of `this`. But, now you can proceed at what you were doing at least :) Don't forget to tick the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some cases when `this` and the name of the object are not referring the same object.

```js
let Foo = {
    prop: 'a',
    log() {
      console.log(
        'this.prop is', this.prop, ', Foo.prop is', Foo.prop
      );
    }
  },
  Bar = {
    prop: 'b',
    mock: Foo.log
  },
  Baz = Object.create(Foo, {
    prop: {
      value: 'c'
    }
  });

Foo.log();
Bar.mock();
Baz.log();

// You can also bind the this reference when calling
Bar.mock.call(Baz);
Baz.log.apply(Bar);
```

In `Baz` case, the original `Foo.prop` preserves its value, since setting a property with the same name in an instance makes it an own property of that instance, the value of the property in the prototype is not overridden.

All of these scenarios help you to reuse already written code, hence reducing the code. Whether this was a goal in your favorite web game or not is not known, when reading the short examples only. With the given code, there's no difference.